# How does 驕's 2021 meanings appertain to its semantic component 馬?

Tags: etymology

I know little about horses.  Did the Chinese think horses were arrogant? Why?

[image]

Above is [Yellowbridge](https://www.yellowbridge.com/chinese/character-etymology.php?searchChinese=1&zi=%E9%A9%95) above.
Below is *Oxford Chinese Dictionary* (2010) p 365.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A horse might not directly represent 'arrogance', but status, wealth, power, elite, proudness, and unruliness are all potential cause of arrogance

- Owning horses was a sign of wealth and power in the time most of the population were farmers
- The number of horses you were allowed to use for a carriage indicated your status, No matter how wealthy you were, if you were not a noble, you could not have a four horses carriage and only the emperor could use a six horses carriage
- Only Elite warriors ride horses
- Wild horses are proud, unruly

Notice: 'proud' and 'arrogant' are very similar, differ mostly in degree of outward expression. 'proud' is more likely the original meaning of 骄 and 'arrogant' is a logical extension

Answer (score 1):

Tl;dr: Simply put, yes (point 1.). But there are etymological uncertainties (points 2. and 3.).

---

0. I do not think ownership or riding of a horse (i.e., the horse-owner or -rider) contributes etymologically to the meaning of the character. That is to say, I believe this is rather far-fetched.

> 馬高六尺爲驕。从馬，喬聲。《詩》曰：我馬唯驕。一曰：野馬。

1. **The above is the *Shuowen* explanation for `驕`: a six-feet horse. 'Sturdiness' (or 'strength', see `驕陽`, 'scorching sun') and 'pride; arrogance' are probably derived from its impressive stature. (Shuowen also gives the explanation 'a wild horse'. Duan Yucai (段玉裁) from the Qing Dynasty thinks 'arrogance' arises from here: `一曰野馬。凡驕恣之義當是由此引伸。`) At any rate, there is semantic extension from an equine adjective to a general adjective.**
2. How credible is *Shuowen*? It gives the *Shijing* citation `我馬唯驕`, but this is not found in existing versions of *Shijing*. We find `駒` in place of `驕` in *Brilliant are the Flowers* (皇皇者華):

   > 我馬維駒，六轡如濡。載馳載驅，周爰咨諏。
   >
   > 我馬維騏，六轡如絲。載馳載驅，周爰咨謀。
   >
   > 我馬維駱，六轡沃若。載馳載驅，周爰咨度。
   >
   > 我馬維駰，六轡既均。載馳載驅，周爰諮詢。

   `維` here functions like a copula,<sup>1</sup> suggesting syntactical equivalence between `我馬` ('my horse') and the characters containing the 馬-radical. It is therefore fairly certain that `駒`, `騏`, `駱`, and `駰` are types of horses, or equine adjectives. In fact, they mean 'young horse', 'piebald horse', 'white and black-maned horse', and 'gray horse' (trans. James Legge) respectively.
3. We are certain that `驕` should also be a type of horse, or an equine adjective; the only uncertainty is whether there is equivalence between `驕` (a six-feet horse) and `駒` (a young horse). Duan Yucai, with the help of two other Odes, argues the original character should be `驕`, but it was changed to `駒` for the sake of rhyme (with `濡` and `諏`; `三詩義皆當作驕而俗人多改作駒者，以駒與蔞株濡諏爲韵。驕則非韵。`). Logically, young horses can yet be ridden (`駒未可駕車。故三詩斷非用駒本義。`); therefore Duan is a proponent of retaining `驕` in the verse.

<sup>1</sup> 呂珍玉（2007）《詩經》「維」字用法與詞義研究。興大人文學報，38，33–72。

Answer (score 0):

I found this this, [骄](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E9%AA%84/5174341?fr=aladdin) is simplied 驕.

> 马高六尺为骄……本义为马壮健。引申指“自满，自高自大，不服从”   、“猛烈”

A horse with six (ancient Chinese) feet hight is 骄 whose original meaning is "strong horse", gradually it was used to describe pride / arrogant or unruly related meanings.

[image]